# copying code from VS Code to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I have coded an html and css website in VS Code. Viewed the project in a web browser (Chrome), looks good. I am on a team and we have created a project using Razor Pages in Visual Studio 2019. I copied my VS Code to Visual Studio 2019 to the appropriate page, in this case WelcomePage.cshtml. When I went to view my Visual Studio 2019 page in a browser (Chrome), it didn't look the same. The styling was off. I have ensured the css and images are pointed to the correct folder. Ensured all my tags are in order. I also checked to see if the Layout.cshtml file and bootstrap.css files were interfering and it's not. I am still experiencing issues with how the page looks in VS Code when I view it in browser compared to what it looks like in Visual Studio 2019. I appreciate any advice and guidance you can share with me. Thank you.

I commented out the Layout.cshtml file and bootstrap.css file. Created a new project where I deleted the Layout.cshtml file, the bootstrap files and js files. Still had the same issue.